# Why session attributes are not rendering remotely in nextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a nextJs application and used next-auth library for the authentication. I need to render the email in the nave bar of my application. So I got the email of the user from the session as shown below.

```
import {useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
...
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  ...
  return (
    <Dropdown.Item panel style={{ padding: 10, width: 160 }}>
      <p>Signed in as</p>
      <strong>{session?.user?.email}</strong>
    </Dropdown.Item>
    ...
  )
```

The issue is, it's only working locally, but it's rendering remotely. If this is the default behavior, what may be the better solution for this??

and this is my api/auth/[...nextauth].tsx file

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
providers: [
  CognitoProvider({
    clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID || '',
    clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
    issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER || '',
  })
],
secret:'sdg=',
callbacks: {
async jwt({token, account}) {
  if (account) {
    token.access_token = account.access_token
    token.id_token = account.id_token
  }
  return token
},
async session({ session, token }) {
  session.access_token = token.access_token;
  session.id_token = token.id_token;  
  return session;
},
}
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Comment: How are you defining your production environment variables? What service are you deploying to? Vercel?

Comment: It's deployed in AWS Fargate